# Can I use DataTables to import data from one database into another?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, data-migration

I need to create a quick and dirty solution to migrate data from database into another. This is only being used a proof of concept. Long term we will use .NET's Sync Framework.

The databases are identical. The solution is going to be used as an OCA (occasionally connected application).

- I read in which tables they want to migrate from some XML.
- Disable all constraints on the target for each table.
- For each table they want to migrate data from I create a DataTable from the source.
- Create a DataTable pointing to the target.
- Import all the rows from the source into the target and insert them
- Enable all constraints on the target tables again.

I am not sure if the above is possible. I had most of it working and I was cloning the source DataTable. I then had the problem where the cloned DataTable wasn't pointing anywhere.

- Can I point it to the target and then insert?
- Is there a better way to do this?
- The alternative is to create INSERT INTO statements, using metadata to identify identity columns and not include them in the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're proposing should work. But you might find it easier (and you'll definitely see better performance) with the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class.

(This is a code-focused solution)

Comment: I had picked up an ADO.Net book. That is the next chapter. Seems quite cool. I will give that a try too maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can load your `DataTable` and save it into another database by using a different `DataAdapter`.

But, for a code less approach, you can to use [SQL Server Database Publishing Toolkit](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/19/update-of-sql-server-database-publishing-toolkit-for-web-hosting.aspx) as [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787345/how-can-i-export-data-from-sql-server).

Comment: Ah yes. I recall seeing this. I use a DataAdapter and SqlCommandBuilder to get this right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Sql Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) (dtswizard.exe).
It creates an Integration Services package that you can then save and execute whenever you want.